# Polling multiple twitter accounts for tweet impression and likes

Tags: java, twitter, java-stream, twitter-streaming-api

I'm currently working on a use case (developed in Java,Spring) where I've large no. of twitter accounts (no. of accounts can go to thousand) to which I can post data(tweet) as when configured/scheduled.

I've implemented posting of data to twitter but I'm confused how to pull impressions/retweets and likes of tweets from various twitter accounts.

One solution is to poll all accounts on regular interval, but in that case I won't be getting no of likes on tweet made, because I'm using user and mentions timeline APIs with "since_id" parameter, which do not return no of likes on my older tweets as it always fetches latest tweet and retweet.

Another option is to use streaming APIs, in which I will be opening a stream for every twitter account I have but that doesn't seems feasible to me because I have very large no. of twitter accounts with me and I doubt that my Java app can handle that many no. of streams.

Can someone please suggest how can I solve this, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

IT seems your problem is due to scale rather then the design ,the statement "and I doubt that my Java app can handle that many no. of streams."

let's look in a different direction.

It's time to move to the world of "Big Data".
Apache kafa,Pig,Hive,Yarn,Strom,HBase,Hadoop etc.list is overwhelming.

1. Apache Spark- large-scale data processing that and supports concepts such as MapReduce, in-memory processing, stream processing, graph processing etc.
2. Storm was created by Twitter the counter part you can say is Apache storm.
3. Apache Kafka it offers brokers that collect streams, log and buffer them in a fault tolerant manner.
4. Hadoop for storage of the data.
   http://www.itworld.com/article/2827285/big-data/what-hadoop-can--and-can-t-do.html

happy designing.